# how to specify multiple format string in fprintf function?

Tags: printf

I want to print many, for example 100, floating point number into one file line using the format string %10.2f. Are there any ways to do this without writing the format string 100 times in the fprintf call or must I using the for loop to print one at a time? I know it's easy to achieve this in Fortan:

```
`fwrite(fd,'(100F10.2)') data`
```

Are there an alternative in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop. That will be able to print 100 floating point numbers